# How to interpet (a==ca)++a;a+=(a)?3.55/2+'d'-'a':13.9; in C

Tags: c, syntax

I have the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    enum e{ca,be};int a=0;
    if (a==ca)++a;a+=(a)?3.55/2+'d'-'a':13.9;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

and ask me the output of this program.

I know that if `enum e{ca,be}` is declared, then `ca=0` and `be=1`.

I do not understand how to interpret the line

```c
if (a==ca)++a;a+=(a)?3.55/2+'d'-'a':13.9;
```

I know what does the ternary operator `[expr1]?[expr2]:[expr3]`: evaluates `expr1`, if it is true then goes to `expr2`, otherwise goes to `expr3`. But here we have a `;` in `(a==ca)++a;a+=(a)`, so I do not know how to delimit the range of the ternary operator.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your reply. Sorry I do not understand what you mean; I am asking about interpreting some code.

Comment: There is an `if`. `if (smth) ++a;` Then ternary operator follows.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, the answer is 5! I do not understand why `if (smth) ++a;` then ternary operator is true. Could you elaborate it, please? Thank you.

Comment: @uneven_mark ok, thank you! Now I am having trouble understanding the role of the `if`. A line is `if (a==ca)++a;`, another line is `a+=(a) ? 3.55/2+'d'-'a' : 13.9;`. What is the connection between the first one and the second one?

Comment: @uneven_mark thank you, it has become clear to me how `if` works in this source code.

Comment: 'I have the following code'............Why?  How?   It's horrible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if (a==ca)++a;a+=(a)?3.55/2+'d'-'a':13.9;

Can be rewritten as:

```
if (a==ca) {
   ++a;
}
a+=(a)?3.55/2+'d'-'a':13.9;
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
if (a == ca) {
   ++a;
}
double tmp;
if (a) {
    tmp = 3.55/2+'d'-'a';
} else {
    tmp = 13.9;
}
a += tmp;
```

Now `int a = 0` and the first enum value is equal to 0 and `enum e{ca,be}`. So `if (a == ca)` will always be true, as both are 0. So we get:

```
++a;
double tmp;
if (a) {
    tmp = 3.55/2+'d'-'a';
} else {
    tmp = 13.9;
}
a += tmp;
```

After `++a`, `a` was 0, so it will become 1. So `if (a)` will always be true. So it becomes:

```
a = 1
a += 3.55/2+'d'-'a';
```

Let's enumerate `a, b, c, d` with numbers `1, 2, 3, 4`. We can translate `'d' - 'a'` into `4 - 1`, which is `3`.

The `3.55 / 2` is equal to `1.775` and has the type `double`. Because of integer promotions, the whole expression on the right side of `+=` has the type `double`. Then `1.775` is added with `3` (promoted from `int` type to `double`) so we get `4.775` (it doesn't happen in this order (an non-optimizing compiler would first do `/`, then `+`, then `-`), but the result would be equal).

So this is:

```
a = 1
a += (double)4.775;
```

The `double` value is converted into `int`, as `a` has `int` type. A floating point value converted to `int` is rounded towards zero, so `4.775` becomes `4`.

So the answer is `5`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought `++a` was part of the condition, not the result. So after the `if` we have `a=1` (because `a==ca` is true). Then we have to evaluate the expression `a+=(a)`: since `a=1` we are asking if `1+=1` i.e. `1=1+1` which is false, so we have `13.9`. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Oh my problem was not considering `a += ((a) ? 3.55/2+'d'-'a' : 13.9);` but `( a += (a) ) ? 3.55/2+'d'-'a' : 13.9;`. You were clear, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In c the semicolon `;` means the end of a statement so we could rewrite the line you were having trouble with as follows:

```
if (a==ca){
  ++a;
}
a+=((a)?(3.55/2+'d'-'a'):(13.9));
```

a would evaluate as true adding the value `3.55/2+'d'-'a'` to `a`.

The value of `'d' - 'a'` is 3 and `3.55/2` is somewhere between 1 and 2 therefore this some, once converted to an int is rounded down to 4. Making the final value for `a` = 5

ouput=`5`

## Edit

Assignment should be evaluated after the rhs

so `(a+=(a))?(3.55/2+'d'-'a'):(13.9)`;  becomes `a+=((a)?(3.55/2+'d'-'a'):(13.9));`

a is still 1 at this point so the value 3.55/2 +'d'-'a' would be added to a

Comment: Oh, the rhs of the assignment would totally be evaluated first. You're right.